# knitr, RwordPress quotations and ampersand changes

Tags: r, wordpress, knitr, rcurl

I followed this [blog post](http://rstudio-pubs-static.s3.amazonaws.com/298828_acfb8248202f416a8dde1c3427c35b1f.html#create-new-post-in-wordpress) and was 99% successful with accomplishing what I wanted to. Basically, create an R Notepad file (.Rmd), run it and save file. Then, run the code that is in the blog post and have my .Rmd file automatically upload to my WordPress site.

The problem is that it uploads and changes the single and double quotes to "&#39";, "&quot" with semicolons at the end, "&amp" respectively.

Example, my code looks like this: `LoggerFile = 'SOLAR_LOGGER'`

When uploaded to WordPress and I look at the post via text only, it shows up like this: "LoggerFile = &#39 ;SOLAR_LOGGER&#39 ;"
Only without the space between ";" and the 9.
When I publish, it still shows "LoggerFile = &#39 ;SOLAR_LOGGER&#39 ;" as well.

I know at one point I messed with my WordPress files to try and implement using pretty print for code which worked. I would normally manually enter "< pre>< code>Code Here" and it would prettify my code. This still works.

A side question: I was trying to post to another WordPress site to see if it was just that particular WordPress configuration but it doesn't seem to want to change sites. I stored site and password in the .Rprofile file. I tried to even put .Rprofile in same directory with no luck. The changes don't take effect, even after restarting R.

I am very new to R so I may be missing some key pieces of the puzzle. I am also new to MacOS and using terminals. Learning quickly and getting the hang of it (loving it as well!).

I'm using WordPress Version 4.9.1
Hosting under godaddy account (sorry!)
R Studio Version 1.0.153
R version 3.4.1 (2017-06-30)
macOS Sierra Version 10.12.6 (16G1036)

Any suggestions?

Comment: Consider blogdown: https://github.com/rstudio/blogdown (I'm the author of knitr, and I don't recommend you to use `knitr::knit2wp()` anymore).

Answer (score 0):

So the answer ended up being a conflict between knit2wp and a Crayon add in for WordPress.

The solution is detailed in this post I found `[here][1]`. Essentially, the code will modify the contents to work well with the Syntax Highlighter built in.

They change knit2wp to knit2wpCrayon. I just tried it and it works perfect. This is good because I won't have to modify any of my old posts.